# What is the right way to use a mapping tables SQL?

Tags: sql

Say I have a simple table that logs import status of a task.

```
    CREATE TABLE ImportLog (
      ImportID int,
      ImportName varchar(255),
      ImportStatus varchar(15),
   )
```

At the moment this table is populated with thousands of rows of data. But the previous developers used Hardcoded strings in the ImportStatus column such as 'SUCCESS', 'FAILED' and 'DUPLICATE'.

I want to change this to use a mapping table for the ImportStatus like below.

```
CREATE TABLE ImportStatus (
  ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  Status varchar(10) NOT NULL
)
```

I want to use the Id as a Foreign key in my ImportLog table in the ImportStatus Column.
Is this possible?
In order to implement this mapping table going forward would I also need to amend the existing data to reflect the new mapping information?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is totaly do-able. You can first populate ImportStatus by selecting distinct values from the ImportLog table. Then you'd UPDATE the ImportLog table using a join on the ImportStatus to get and use the ID.

At the same time, you'd have to change ALL the code that uses the table to do the correct join so you get the right status as expected...

This seems like a very big headache for just the 3 values you listed. IMO there is no real reason to complicate all this like you plan to. Unless statuses will get modified, deleted, inserted daily.

The only suggestion I'd do, if there are only 3 values is to use an enum instead of  a varchar. That way you'd still have the benefit of not allowing any value in like the foreign key would do, but you'd have the right information at the right time without having to join or anything, and your current code will still work.

Comment: When you say use an ENUM you mean in the backend code that interacts with the table. An ENUm type is not available in SQL Server? @Salketer

Comment: You are right, MySQL has one but not SQL Server. You could use this column definition tough.

ImportStatus VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL CHECK (ImportStatus IN( 'SUCCESS', 'FAILED','DUPLICATE'))